# Are you allowed to expose the sins of a non-Muslim?

Tags: women, sin, men, halal-haram

I’ve heard that you aren’t allowed to expose the sins of others. But how about non-Muslims? Are you allowed to expose the sins of a non-Muslim by telling your nearest about it?

Comment: Are you referring to [Qur'an 4:148](http://corpus.quran.com/translation.jsp?chapter=4&verse=148)?